# How can i execute at least one method in a mehtod by random

Tags: java

If i have following Method:

```
public void randomDecider(){
  methodA();
  methodB();
  methodC();
  methodD();
  methodE();
}
```

The only thing i want is, that at least one of these Methods gonna be executed. There should be variety. For example:

Excution of:

methodB(); methodC(); methodD();

or
  methodC();

or
  methodA(); methodE()

or all Methods

etc.

I only found something in the forum about to execute only one thing by random. 
but i need this variety.

I hope you can help me.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Random`. This way you can easily set probabilities for given methods if needed.

```
Random r = new Random();
Double d = r.nextDouble();
if(d < 0.75){ // probability 0.75
    methodA();
}
d = r.nextDouble();
if(d < 0.5){ // probability 0.5
    methodB();
}
```

EDIT:

If you want at least one method to be executed, you can use a flag for example:

```
Random r = new Random();
boolean notexecuted = true;
while(notexecuted){
    Double d = r.nextDouble();
    if(d < 0.75){ // probability 0.75
        methodA();
        notexecuted = false;
    }
    d = r.nextDouble();
    if(d < 0.5){ // probability 0.5
        methodB();
        notexecuted = false;
    }
}
```

For equal probabilities use fixed value for example `p = 0.5` (or whatever you want it to be) and check `d < p` condition.

Comment: the probabilities should be the same for every kombination of methods that can be executed. And i want thats possible, that not only one method gonna be executed.

Comment: @kasy I've updated the answer to maybe better fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a randomly generated bitset to determine which methods should be executed. A simple int can be used as a bitset here. e.g.

```
public void randomDecider() {
  int set = rand.nextInt(31) + 1; //we need a 5 bit number with at least one bit in it set to 1
  if((set & 1) == 1) methodA();
  if(((set >> 1) & 1) == 1) methodB();
  if(((set >> 2) & 1) == 1) methodC();
  if(((set >> 3) & 1) == 1) methodD();
  if(((set >> 4) & 1) == 1) methodE();
}
```

Here is a more generic was of doing this using method references.

```
Runnable[] methods = {
  this::methodA, this::methodB, this::methodC,
  this::methodD, this::methodE
};

public void randomDecider() {
  int set = rand.nextInt((1 << methods.length) - 1) + 1;
  for(int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
    if(((set >>> i) & 1) == 1) methods[i].run();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. its genius. i used the first one in my project :)

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer, as it is the one you used, and the most concise. Regards.